# How can a regular user circumvent a restriction on running ls imposed by root?

Tags: permissions, ls, executable

Suppose a root user denied all permissions to use the 'ls' command  for a specific regular user in a system. How can that regular user overcome this denial and how can he use 'ls' command with out any 'sudo' command?

Comment: How was that managed (SELinux?)? Or you just get something like "no such command" when you type ls ?

Answer (score 5):

I would say talk to the root user. That user either accidentally did something wrong, or they are a real scumbag (in which case talking to their manager is the better option).

---

Suppose the user is only wanting to view what files and directories are in the current directory, without using `ls`.  `echo *` would do that.

Suppose a user would like to see the ordinary `ls -l` output for the files and directories in the current directory.  `find . -maxdepth 1 -ls` would do that.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the simplest way would be to copy the `ls` binary
from some other system — e.g., over the network, or on a USB thumb drive
— and put it into his private `bin` directory. 
Another workaround is to use `stat` with wildcards.